# inotifywait to monitor shared directory on laravel homestead

Tags: directory, inotify, vagrant, shared-folders

I need to watch a directory that is shared on a network for new files. I used inotifywait from inotify-tools and it is great except when the file is added from the other place.

For example: I am using laravel Homestead on vagrant. I "share" my /Code directory. When I `vagrant ssh` and run `inotifywait DirectoryName` it will show me when files are added to that directory. If I add it to the same directory on my local environment it does not trigger. I can `ls -l` and see that the file is there but Inotify never caught it.

Any ideas? From my research I know inotify doesn't work great with shared drives but I figured it would show something.

Sorry if this would've been better on StackOverflow

Comment: Are you sure your issue is not a limitation of the VirtualMachine Software?

Comment: It may be. Gosh that hand't even occurred to me. I'll try and get some sort of test environment for it. To your knowledge is it supposed to work?

Comment: Well Every manual I've read states the contrary.  Cygwin states something like: Be careful when moving or copying files in Windows, when logged into Cygwin.  VirtualBox will let you, as long as you only do it in the Shared Folders Tab, but like Cygwin, it grays out most settings when the VM is running, plus you are using Vagrant, which may require some settings change.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try and get a server to test it with.